# Displaytag / Spring MVC pagination

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have a Spring MVC based JSP page which uses Displaytag to display a set of data.   In the form on the page, the user can select either, or both of two checkboxes to display which subset of the data they want to see (Set "O", set "Q", or "B" both.)

The form and the display work fine on the first page, but the Displaytag pagination links at the bottom of the table contain malformed URLs.  The result is that when the user clicks a link to display a different page, the checkboxes are reset and the user always sees  "Both O and Q" even if they only wanted to see "Q" (for example).

I have added this parameter to the form that Displaytag uses to generate these URLs (according to the Displaytag documentation) but the value in the generated URLs does not change.

The form entry (type="o"):

```
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="o">
```

The pagination URL (type="b" for both):

```
http://localhost:8080/searchmain.html?d-443691-p=3&endDate=&_stateQuote=on&type=b&stateOrder=true
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Does anyone know how the URL parameters are generated?

Comment: Show us the source code. By default, the display tag appends all the parameters used to load the page to the URLs of its pagination and sorting links. It should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - posting it here so hopefully it will help someone else.

Displaytag generates the URL parameters for its pagination using the parameters on your initial HTTP REQUEST, not the RESPONSE.   So if you are depending on some updated parameters coming back (as was this case), then your paging will produce incorrect results.   In this case, the two checkboxes on the page were being used to update the hidden "type" field which was then passed back in the response.   Unfortunately, the paging URLs were updated with the "type" field from the REQUEST which still contained the previous un-updated value (example "B") instead of the new updated value "O".

Whatever values you are hoping to find in the URL will have to be on the HTTP REQUEST you pass in, you cannot expect to utilize anything from the RESPONSE.

Makes sense, it just took a while to find it.

If you want to see the actual code, it's in this routine in TableTag.java in the [Displaytag](http://sourceforge.net/projects/displaytag/) source:

```
protected void initHref(RequestHelper requestHelper)
```